# What is the orange coloured cream inside McAloo Tikki called and what are its ingredients?

Tags: indian-cuisine, restaurant-mimicry

The McAloo Tikki:

[image: McAloo Tikki]

([McDonalds' official page](http://www.mcdonaldsindia.com/happy-meals-menu.html) has a smaller image.)

I have seen the onions, tomatoes, Aloo Tikki, and ***an orange coloured cream*** inside this burger.
**I wish to know what is that cream called and what are its ingredients?**

Comment: I'm not sure.. But i think its mayonnaise with some red paprika...

Comment: A bit of google searching suggests some kind of vegetarian mayo, yes. Ingredients could be anything in that case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot speak to its accuracy as I have no experience with this item or McDonald's at all outside the US, but [Time In Kitchen](http://timeinkitchen.blogspot.com/2011/09/mc-aloo-tikki-burger.html) in their recipe for a homemade version indicates:

> For sauce, beat hung curd in bowl and add pinch of salt and tomato
>   ketchup and mix well to smoothen it in order to avoid any lumps and
>   keep it aside

Then again, according to [SipputySup](http://www.sippitysup.com/mcalootikkiburgerrecipe), it is "basically Thousand Island dressing)".

This question itself now appears on the 2nd page of google results when searching for "Aloo Tikki sauce" :-)

Comment: "basically Thousand Island dressing" Couldn't understand this, sorry.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand_Island_dressing

Comment: Okay, I thought they coined the phrase themselves. Didn't know better.

Comment: I would rather have peanut butter, myself :-)

Comment: These western country foods aren't seen commonly here. I'll have to hunt the shop now!

Comment: :( Many websites don't agree with you. Google: ***"mcdonalds thousand island dressing"***

Comment: It is essentially mayonnaise mixed with tomato ketchup. I wouldn't imagine McDonald's get much fancier than that with it.

Comment: Anisha, I don't know what you mean about websites agreeing or disagreeng.  I am not advocating anything.  I reported what two websites said, and gave you a baseline reference about Thousand Island dressing.  I don't have anything thoughts at all on McDonalds use or failure to use a traditional or non-traditional version of that sauce.   I try to avoid eating there if at all reasonably possible, on the grounds that their food is just plain bad (fries excepted) in my opinion.

Comment: If you are actually interested in a recreation of the US-McDonalds "secret sauce" (I find it hard to imagine why), Kenki Alt's obsessively geeky Big Mac re-creation/improvement recipe contains a sub-recipe for making the sauce.  http://aht.seriouseats.com/archives/2011/05/the-burger-lab-building-a-better-big-mac.html

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ or, for the "secret" Big Mac sauce, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcu4Bj3xEyI

Comment: Thousand Island dressing has pickle relish in it - that is what gives it the look of 1,000 islands.  (Actually, I should SNOPE this!) :-)

Answer (score 5):

Hung Curd + Tomato Ketchup + pinch of Salt, Sugar and Vinger. And you are home. I tried at home and its the closest.

Comment: what is "hung curd"?

Comment: @rumtscho Sometimes YouTube is even better than Google! :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sshp7tiP7Pk (I did verify that hung curd = hung yoghurt)

Comment: Some authors also refer to hung curd as "Yogurt cheese".

Answer (score 4):

It's simple. Put tomato ketchup in a bowl then add *milk cream*, also known as *malai* in Hindi with a pinch of salt and pepper. Just mix it all together.

Answer (score 4):

They list it as “Tom Mayo” sauce on their website.[image: Mcdelivery McAloo customisation]

On further web search I find that the “Tom Mayo” means Tomato Mayonnaise only.

Answer (score 2):

It's tomato ketchup, cream, mayo, salt, white pepper powder, some sweet chilli sauce or powdered sugar and chilli powder, and parsley if you like.

Answer (score 1):

the orange sauce is just a mixture of mayo and ketchup

Answer (score -1):

A Recipe for the sauce is

- 1/4 Cup of Mayo
- 2 tbsp ketchup
- 1/2 tbsp of smoked paprika

I tried this and it is almost the same. We don't have Aloo tikki burger available in USA so we have to find such alternates.

Answer (score -2):

it is mayonaise,i think.
it's sooooooo tasty and it's the only thing i like about ncallo tikki burger.

Comment: I don't think mayonnaise is orange.

Comment: Is there something added to the mayonnaise?

Comment: Mayonnaise color is very much a function of yolk color, and orange yolks aren't unheard off.

Answer (score -2):

Its liquid cheess  mixture of processed cheese and permezan cheese

Comment: This would taste very different from the other suggestions (variations on spiced mayonnaise and thousand island dressing), are you speaking from experience?